# Entity Framework: How do I invoke pairs of entities from a raw query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

For instance, I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM
persons
LEFT JOIN vehicles
ON persons.Id = vehicles.OwnerId
```

I would like execute this query on an EF data context and have array of pairs "person-vehicle". how do I do it?

Another example:

```
SELECT persons.*, COUNT(vehicles.*) as cnt FROM
persons
JOIN vehicles
ON persons.Id = vehicles.OwnerId
GROUP BY vehicles.Id
```

Here I want to have a dictionary of a person as a key and number of vehicles he owns as a value.

I know that these quesies are simple enough and it's better to avoid raw sql in these cases. But I want to know possibilities of raw query handling, because real life queries can be much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do some reading ion LINQ to Entities. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386964(v=vs.100).aspx

The first one is pretty basic:

```
var persons = context.Persons
                     .Include(p => p.Vehicles) 
                     .ToList();
```

The second one is a little more advanced:

```
var persons = context.Persons
                     .Select(p => new { Person p, VehicleCount = p.Vehicles.Count() }
                     .ToList();
```

You could also do a group by which is described in the link.

Comment: As I mentioned in the title, I want to know how to achieve same using a raw SQL. I.e. something like this:
 var l = dbSet.Persons.
 SqlQuery("SELECT p.*, COUNT(c.Id) as cnt FROM People as p JOIN Cars as c ON p.Id = c.OwnerId GROUP BY p.Id")
 *some code here to get Person and cars count*
 .ToList();

Comment: OK, so your issue isn't really entity framework since you know you can use LINQ and run raw queries (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx). If you need assistance with query syntax you should add a SQL tag.

Comment: Yes, my question is about sql linq raw queries, as mentioned in the title :) but it's not about sql syntax but about linq approaxch to return values

Comment: The LINQ approach to return values from a raw query is: var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList(); so if you have your query simply replace the select statement with yours. If it involves aggregates, you can add groupby.